# Cron Logging Issue

Tags: cron

I cannot find documentation on how to set up Cron commands for some reason. Here's my current Cron command using GoDaddy's cron job manager tool. It runs twice an hour.

/web/cgi-bin/php5 "$HOME/~path-to-file~/my-function.php" > "$HOME/~path-to-file~/my-function.log"

What I'd like to do is get a thorough log of each time the Cron runs - output, timestamp, etc. I'm trying to debug this script and I'm stuck without some kind of error logging.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You are directing Standard Output to the specified file by `>`, but Standard Error gets sent into oblivion. Add `2>&1` to the end of the command to append any errors to the same file.

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 /path/to/php > /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1
```